# How to use grep in an if statement?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have the following command which gives me the correct result:

`grep --include='*.java' -Ri 'System.loadLibrary' *`

However, if I put it in an if condition, it always returns the same 0 result, no matter if the string exists or not:

`if [ "grep --include='*.java' -Ri 'System.loadLibrary' *" = 0 ] then ...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you expecting a string (which just happens to be a command you want to run) to equal the string `0`?

Comment: @EtanReisner: I thought I had to compare the value returned by grep with 0 to check if it had found anything.

Comment: The return code and the output are not the same thing. Running a command and the string value of the command are not the same thing. That was my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep -q` option:

```
if grep -q --include='*.java' -Ri 'System.loadLibrary' .; then
   echo "found a matching file"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-q` as for a quiet output and directly say:

```
if grep -q ....; then
   # things
```

Or even a short circuit operator if there will just be one action to perform:

```
grep -q ... && echo "yes"
```

#### Test

```
$ echo "23" > a
$ grep -q 23 a && echo "yes" || echo "no"
yes
$ grep -q 45 a && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```